# php script executed from cron acting weird

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a Centos 7 server . I have this php script ( conn.php ) which executes a shell command to calculate number of SMTP connections and save them in /usr/local/conn.txt

```
    <?php
$conn=rtrim(shell_exec("ss -tn | egrep \":25 |:26 |:587 |:465 \" | egrep \"^ESTAB\" | awk '{print $4}' | egrep -c \":25|:26|:587|:465\" >> /usr/local/conn.txt " ));
?>
```

If I execute the script from console

```
 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php-cgi /usr/local/conn.php
```

it works perfectly and saves in /usr/local/conn.txt the correct number of SMTP connections. e.g.

```
15
24
56
34
12
```

But if I set a root cron like this to execute the script each 2 minutes

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php-cgi /usr/local/conn.php
```

the script saves in /usr/local/conn.txt only a long series of 0 (a zero each time the cron executes)

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

How can avoid this ? Why the script does not return the correct value if executed from root cron ?

Comment: put fully qualified paths for each command you use, `egrep, ss, awk`

Comment: Is there more to your PHP script, is it supposed to insert any dynamic values into the command? If not, why the detour via a PHP script in the first place, why not execute your shell command _directly_ via cron?

Comment: because the script does other actions, I put here only the problem to explain you the issue.